# Response.Redirect bad seed or just misunderstood

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Recently I posted a answer to a question that I thought was quite an easy one, The question was about issues with the lifecyle of the page in asp.net where items would only reflect the changes made after the first postback, so I suggested using

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

And almost instantly got voted down for this as (Why cause another round trip)

Well I want your suggestion, is this type of thing good practise, simply practical or should never be used, please back up your answer with a little motivation its something I do from time to time and now question if I should rethink it.

This is the original post
[Dynamically Change User Control in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987680/dynamically-change-user-control-in-asp-net/987727#987727)

Comment: I think - on the earlier question and on this one - you have your answers. R.R should not be used (because of resource considerations and misleading intent) if a redirect is not actually required. The session based solution Joel presents, or pulling from Request directly both solve the original problem handily. (the JS solution also works, but ASP.NET doesn't play well with it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with Reponse.Redirect, just in most cases it isn't required in that kind of situation.  You can change the way the page is constructed by working with the lifecycle rather than against it. Then there shouldbe no need for another postback.

Comment: I think the first statement should be more strongly worded: there very much is something wrong with a Response.Redirect not used for redirecting. I don't think this is a case of better techniques so much as it really is outright wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.Net page lifecycle provides plenty of opportunities to step in and set things up, so I don't see that it would be necessary to use `Response.Redirect` to make the client load the page twice.

As an aside, using Response.Redirect with just the one argument can throw a `ThreadAbortException`, so it's often best to use the overload `Response.Redirect(string url, bool endResponse)` with the second argument set to false. This definitely applies to ASP.Net 1.0 and 1.1 (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629)), not sure about 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use an UpdatePanel with an AutoPostBack DropDownList to switch the user controls, then that is only responsible for switching the user control, and when the main submit button (or other event) posts back the whole form, you can process all of the data.

UpdatePanels do update the local page ViewState, if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like programming by coincidence, but much of ASP.net is that.