# Dynamically Swap UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987680/dynamically-change-user-control-in-asp-net), but I am facing trouble to implement the solution shown there.

In my case I have two links, **User Settings**, **Space Settings** and two **UserControls**, viz, `UserSettings.ascx`, `SpaceSettings.ascx`.

- On first time when user will visit the page he will see the **User Settings**.
- Depending on which one of these two links has been clicked, the **PlaceHolder** will swap **UserControl**.

What I have done is shown below:

```
public partial class SiteSettings : RefreshDitectedPage {   

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnInit(e);
        string key = Session["Settings"] as String;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);
        if (key == null) {
        Session["Settings"] = "User";           
        AddUserSettings();
        } else {
        if (key.Equals("User")) {
            AddUserSettings();
        } else {
            AddSpaceSettings();
        }
        }
    }


    protected void SettingsLink_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs commandEventArgs) {
        switch (commandEventArgs.CommandName) {
        case "User":
            Session["Settings"] = "User";           
            AddUserSettings();
            break;

        case "Space":
            Session["Settings"] = "Space";
            AddSpaceSettings();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void AddUserSettings() {
        AddSettings(LoadControl("~/UserControls/UserSettings.ascx") as UserSettings);
    }

    private void AddSpaceSettings() {
        AddSettings(LoadControl("~/UserControls/SpaceSettings.ascx") as SpaceSettings);
    }

    private void AddSettings(UserControl control) {
        SettingsPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();
        SettingsPlaceholder.Controls.Add(control);
    }

    /*protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Session["Settings"] = null;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unload called");
    }*/

    }
```

This is not working. The results are:

- On first time visit the Session["Settings"] is null and the **UserControl** `UserSettings.ascx` has been loaded(Right) and Log from `Page_Load` method of `UserSettings.ascx.cs` has been displayed in Output window(Right).
- When the **Space Settings** link has been clicked, the **UserControl** `SpaceSettings.ascx` has been loaded(Right) but in Output window it is printing *User* (Wrong) also the Logs from the `Page_Load` methods of both `UserSettings.ascx.cs` and `SpaceSettings.ascx.cs` have been displayed(`UserSettings.ascx.cs`'s Log is wrong).
- When the **User Settings** link has been clicked, the **UserControl** `UserSettings.ascx` has been loaded(Right) but in Output window it is printing *Space* (Wrong) also the Logs from the `Page_Load` methods of both `UserSettings.ascx.cs` and `SpaceSettings.ascx.cs` have been displayed(`SpaceSettings.ascx.cs`'s Log is wrong).
- I have added two **Buttons** to each one of the **UserControls** and when, say, the Button of `SpaceSettings.ascx` has been clicked it is not firing the Event in backing class first time, but it does if it is being clicked for the second time. Fist time it is Logging *User* (Wrong) and second time *Space* (Right) then the event is going to fired.
- When I visit the page second time I am seeing the control, which was loaded last. Since the `Session["Settings"]` is not null then. I have tried to set this value to null in `Page_Unload` and in `OnUnload` methods but both of them are not working. `Page_Unload` is breaking the system, since it is being called every time while `PostBack` and `OnUnload` is not being called atall.

I have tried to use `Request["Settings"]` instead of `Session["Settings"]`, but `Request["Settings"] = "User"` and `Request["Settings"] = "Space"` are giving me compile time error:

```
Property or indexer 'System.Web.HttpRequest.this[string]' cannot be assigned to
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might wait for others to comment on how to resolve it, but isn't it time to switch to jQuery for such client side tabs? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Comment: @Lex Li why should I use jQuery tab in this case? I guess then I have to load all the contents on page load and that would be very bad.

Comment: jQuery tabs supports AJAX, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried a different approach to solve my requirement, and that solves the swapping of **UserControl** but then I encountered that the **EventHandlers** of the **Buttons** of the **UserControls** were not being fired first time, but were firing if it is being clicked twice.

I asked this question in ASP.NET forum. But there nobody answered to my question. But I was trying die hard to find the solution and atlast I made it possible. The problem was in the ID. I had posted the solution in that forum.

Here is the [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1793056.aspx/1?Dynamically%20Swapped%20UserControl%20EventListeners%20of%20Buttons%20of%20UserControls%20are%20not%20firing). This might be useful for future users.